# Calling a method which is inside a class in python from a robot file

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have a python class and the name of the file is one.py

```
class one:
   def __init__(self,dict1,connect=False):
       self.device=dict1['device']
       self.ip=dict1['ip']
       self.uname=dict1['uname']
       self.password=dict1['password']
       self.dict1={'device':self.device, 'ip':self.ip,'uname':self.uname,self.password:self.password}
       self.is_connect=False
       self.is_config_mode=False
       if connect:
         self.connects_to()
   def connects_to(self):
       netconn=ConnectionHandler(self.dict1)
       print "stuff"
```

I need to call the function connects_to from the robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library LibFiles/one.py
Library OperatingSystem
Library String
Library Collections
*** Keywords ***
Test_1 ${equip1}
${dict1}= Create Drictionary device=auto1 ip:192.38.19.20 secret=${EMPTY} uname=Adrija password=Hello port=22
${a}= connects_to ${dict1} connect=${True}
```

But the error that I am getting is the method connects_to() doesnt exists.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the exact wording of the error. It's telling you precisely what the problem is. Read it closely, and take it literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above Robot Script lacks the double spaces to divide the arguments. I'm assuming that this is a formatting issue, and not part of the overall problem. I've also changed `ip:192..` to `ip=192..` and changed keyword call `connects_to` to `Connects To`,

In the Python Library there are two methods defined: `init` and `connect_to`. In Robot Framework these two methods map to the following events: loading of the library `Library /LibFiles/one.py` and calling of the keyword `connect to`.

The main problem is that when you load the library you're not specifing the required variables. In the below Robot Example I'm specifying the variables in the `variables` section and then using those in the `settings` section.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  one    ${dict1}    connect=${True}

*** Variables ***
&{dict1}    device=auto1  ip=192.38.19.20  secret=${EMPTY}  uname=Adrija  password=Hello port=22
```

If you do not want to make that connection at load time, but when connecting, then the code and variables need to be specified in the `Connects To` keyword. Below is the modified code.

**one.py**

```
class one(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
       pass

    def connects_to(self, dict1=False, connect=False):
       self.device=dict1['device']
       self.ip=dict1['ip']
       self.uname=dict1['uname']
       self.password=dict1['password']
       self.dict1={'device':self.device, 'ip':self.ip,'uname':self.uname,self.password:self.password}
       self.is_connect=False
       self.is_config_mode=False

       # netconn=ConnectionHandler(self.dict1)
       print "stuff"
```

**Robot Script**

```
*** Settings ***
Library  one
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test_1
    ${dict1}=  Create Dictionary  device=auto1  ip=192.38.19.20  secret=${EMPTY}  uname=Adrija  password=Hello port=22
    ${a}=  Connects To  ${dict1}  connect=${True}

Test_2
    ${one}    Get Library Instance    one
    ${one.ip}    Set Variable    123.123.123.123
    ${test}    Set Variable    ${one.ip}
    Log To Console    ${test}
```

It should be noted that some editors may have issues when pre loading libraries for keyword discovery. They typically load the library without passing any variables to the `init` method and thus cause an error. Simply allowing for default values and checking for those would solve that issue.

Edit: Added a second example for directly associating values to Python Object variables.

Comment: Hi @A. Kootstra, thanks for the help. But I have a question, the dict1 vlaues are already declared in the init function, is it mandatory again to define in the robot file? Or is there a way of directly calling the dict1 from python. Thanks.

Comment: This is possible, see the updated answer for the second example. However, I'd recommend against it for maintainability reasons. If you're going to directly update Python variables from your robot script, then when you change your Python code, your Robot Code needs to change as well. By using a method to update the variable you can make these changes more easily with lower overall impact.

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra, I have one question. So if I need to create an instance of the class one, is there a way of calling the subsequent functions using the instance of the class. Thanks again, for helping.