# Creating instances of python class from Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am very new to robot framework. I am trying to create object of a python class from Robot framework. 
The following is the python code:

```
class sample():
  def __init__(self,dict1,connect=True):
     self.device=dict1['device']
     self.ip=dict1['ip']
     self.uname=dict1['uname']
     self.password=dict1['password']
     self.dict1={'device':self.device,'ip':self.ip,'uname':self.uname,password:self.password}
     self.is_connect=False
     self.is_config_mode=False
     if connect:
        self.connects_to()
  def connect_to(self):
     print('stuff')
```

I need to make an object of the class sample in Robot file and use it to call other subsequent methods.
What I did is:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Testing connection
Library Collections
Library RequestsLibrary
Library      sample.sample  ${dict1}    WITH NAME    obj
```

***Variables***

```
*** Keywords ***
Test_Connection ${name}  
   [Documentation]    Testing connection
   ${a}=    obj.connect_ssh
```

I am getting the following error:

Test Library 'sample' expected 1 to 2 arguments, got 0.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer continues with the example provided in my answer to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134803/calling-a-method-which-is-inside-a-class-in-python-from-a-robot-file) 
Loading the same library mutiple times is indeed possible using the `Library  xxx    WITH NAME    xxxyyy` format.

Then you can access all of it's objects properties using the same syntax as the original. In the below example you'll find an example where the `IP` attribute holds a different value in each object:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  one
Library  one    WITH NAME    two
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    ${dict1}=  Create Dictionary  device=auto1  ip=192.38.19.21  secret=${EMPTY}  uname=Adrija  password=Hello port=22
    ${dict2}=  Create Dictionary  device=auto2  ip=192.38.19.22  secret=${EMPTY}  uname=Adrija  password=Hello port=22

    one.connects to  ${dict1}  connect=${True}
    two.connects to  ${dict2}  connect=${True}

    ${one}    Get Library Instance    one
    ${two}    Get Library Instance    two

    Should Be Equal As Strings   ${one.ip}     192.38.19.21
    Should Be Equal As Strings   ${two.ip}     192.38.19.22
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @A.Kootstra

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what values are being passed to  ${dict1} , i had some minor modification to your code and this is able to import library 'sample.py'

Both my .py and .robot file are in same folder

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Testing connection
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    String
Library    Collections
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    DateTime
Library    sample.sample    ${dict1}    WITH NAME    obj
***Variables***
${dict1}    Test
*** Test Cases ***
Test_Connection_String
    Test_Connection    name

*** Keywords ***
Test_Connection
   [Arguments]    ${name}
   [Documentation]    Testing connection
   obj.connect_to
```

Comment: Thanks so much @pankaj mishra

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did. :)

```
Library LibFiles/sample.py  WITH NAME    obj_1
Library LibFiles/sample.py  WITH NAME    obj_2

*** Keywords ***
Test_Connection ${Juniper_mse}  
  [Documentation]    Testing connection

  obj_1.connect_ssh
```